# Conditional probability and expectation: Binary variable that depends on the inequality of two exponentially distributed RVs

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

How do I express for the conditional probability and expectation of a binary variable X that depends on the inequality between two other exponentially distributed random variables Y (with rate param $\mu_{i}$) and Z (with rate param $\mu_{j}$)?
I am interested in only the mean of the count on successes, what would the expression for the conditional expectation appear like?

$$P(Y<Z)$$ has already been expressed for [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2561014/pxy-where-x-and-y-are-exponential-with-means-2-and-1)

**Attempt**

Since X obeys a binomial distribution, the pmf for $k$ successes in $n$ trials is given by

$$P(X=k) =  \binom{n}{k} p^kq^{n-k} $$

and the expectation is known from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) as $$E[X] = np$$.
I express the conditional probability as $$P(X|Y<Z) = \frac{P(X=k)P(Y<Z)}{P(Y<Z)}$$.
$$F_{X=k|Y<Z}(x) = P(X|Y<Z) = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{x} \binom{n}{i} p^{i}(1-p)^{n-i} \frac{\mu_{i}}{\mu_{i}+\mu_{j}}}{\frac{\mu_{i}}{\mu_{i}+\mu_{j}}}$$.

Am I doing the right thing here mathematically because I get stuck going ahead.
The expectation would appear like $$E[X|Y<Z]$$ but I still cannot get the a final expression for it.

I would be really grateful for any help here. Thx in advance.

Comment: What is the relationship between $X$ and $Y,Z$? Does the parameter $p$ depend on $\mu_i,\mu_j$ somehow? As it is currently written, it would appear that they are  independent, but I suspect that is not the intention of the problem.

Comment: For example, you have written $$P(X=k|Y<Z)=\frac{P(X=k)P(Y<Z)}{P(Y<Z)},$$ which is correct if $X$ is independent of $Y,Z$ (or even if the event $(X=k)$ is independent of the event $(Y<Z)$). But if they aren't independent, it should be $$P(X=k|Y<Z)=\frac{P((X=k)\cap (Y<Z))}{P(Y<Z)},$$

Comment: Thx @user114263 for the correction. Yes X(a success) depends on the inequality Y<Z. Intuitively, yes, then $p$ the success probability depends on the rate parameters $\mu_{i},\mu_{j}$. Given your correction, does the equation for $F_{X|Y<Z}$ then also change? In it's current state am afraid things cancel out and am left with the binomial expression as final. This is where I feel something is not right. Or am I wrong?

Comment: In order to evaluate $P((X=k)\cap (Y<Z))$, which will depend on $p,\mu_i,\mu_j$, we need to know specifically how $p$ depends on $\mu_1,\mu_2$. Is it equal to $\mu_i/(\mu_i+\mu_j)$?

Separately, you have $P(X|Y<Z)$ being equal to a probability of an event involving an $X=x$ condition, whereas your $F_{X|Y<Z}(x)$ appears to have an $X\leqslant x$. But you have written $F_{X|Y<Z}(x)=P(X|Y<Z)$.

Comment: @user114263 I would say yes because higher deviations between measures in $\mu_{1}$ and $\mu_{2}$ lead to higher probabilities of $p$ if computed using $\frac{\mu_{i}}{\mu_{i}+\mu_{j}}$. Sorry for the confusion with $X=k/X=x$, I have updated the equations. Excuse my notation, hope I didn't introduce more confusion.

Comment: If $X$ just denotes the success of $Y < Z$, isn't $X$ just a Bernoulli random variable with parameter $p = \Pr(Y < Z)$? How did you get that $X$ is binomial? Are there multiple such rounds?

Comment: Thx @sudeep5221, yes multiple runs such that $X=True/1$ if $Y<Z$ else $X=False/0$.

Comment: @ton_K Is it like one generates $n$ i.i.d. copies of $Y$ and $Z$, say $\{Y_1, Y_2, \dots, Y_n\}$ and $\{Z_1, Z_2, \dots, Z_n\}$ and $X = | \{ i : Y_i < Z_i \} |$ ? If so, $X$ is just Binomial with parameters $n$ and $p = \Pr(Y < Z)$. What would $Y$ and $Z$ correspond to in the expression $\mathbb{E}[X|Y < Z]$?

Comment: @sudeep5221 I run a montecarlo experiment to generate $Y$ and $Z$ as two independent rvs where both follow a exponential dist and for each comparison $X$ takes a true/false.